# How to filter date range in reactjs and dynamic data rendering

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs

I want to dynamically render the data when filtering from start to end. The logic only displays one date value at a time. I want to display the E_NodeB Cell_Name   Date    E_RAB_Setup_Success_Rate    Data_Traffic_DL Data_Traffic_UL UL_Throughput when I filter the from and to dates

`const data = "http://localhost:8080/sites";

```
const SelectSingle = () => {
  var traffic = [];
  var rab = [];
  var newData = [];
  const [sites, setsites] = useState([]);
  const [selectedSite, setSelectedSite] = useState([]);
  const [startDate, setDate] = useState();
  const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState();

  // 1
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const siteSelected = event.target.value;
    const itemSelected = sites.filter(
      (site) => site.Cell_Name === siteSelected
    );
    setSelectedSite(itemSelected);
  };

  // Start Date
  // Traffice_Date
  const handleDate = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const siteSelected = "4G_ADONKIA-2";
    const dateChosen = sites.filter((site) => {
      return (
        site.Traffice_Date === getDate(e) && site.Cell_Name === siteSelected
      );
    });

    newData.push(dateChosen);
    setSelectedSite(dateChosen);
  };

  // End date
  const handleEndDate = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const siteSelected = "4G_ADONKIA-2";
    const dateChosen = sites.filter((site) => {
      return (
        site.Traffice_Date === getDate(e) && site.Cell_Name === siteSelected
      );
    });

    setSelectedSite(dateChosen);
  };

  // Get Date Function
  const getDate = (e) => {
    const start = e.target.value;
    const [year, month, day] = start.split("-");
    const newDate = `${day}/${month}/${year}`;
    return newDate;
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(data)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setsites(data));
  });

  selectedSite.map((site) => {
    rab.push(site.E_RAB_Setup_Success_Rate);
    traffic.push(site.Traffice_Date);
  });
  const state = {
    labels: traffic,
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "E_RAB_Setup_Success_Rate",
        backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
        borderColor: "rgba(0,0,0,1)",
        borderWidth: 2,
        data: rab,
      },
    ],
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="data-class">
        <select
          onChange={(e) => {
            handleChange(e);
          }}
        >
          {sites.map((site, index) => (
            <option value={site.Cell_Name} key={index}>
              {site.Cell_Name}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
        <h2>From</h2>
        <input
          type="date"
          value={startDate}
          onChange={(e) => {
            handleDate(e);
          }}
          name="startDate"
        />
        <h2>To</h2>
        <input
          type="date"
          value={endDate}
          onChange={(e) => {
            handleEndDate(e);
          }}
          name="endDate"
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>E_NodeB</th>
              <th>Date</th>
              <th>Cell_Name</th>
              <th>E_RAB_Setup_Success_Rate</th>
              <th>Data_Traffic_DL</th>
              <th>Data_Traffic_UL</th>
              <th>UL_Throughput</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>

          {selectedSite.map((site, index) => (
            <tbody key={index}>
              <td>{site.eNodeB_Name}</td>
              <td>{site.Cell_Name}</td>
              <td>{site.Traffice_Date}</td>
              <td>{site.E_RAB_Setup_Success_Rate}</td>
              <td>{site.Data_Traffic_DL}</td>
              <td>{site.Data_Traffic_UL}</td>
              <td>{site.G_UL_Throughput_IK}</td>
            </tbody>
          ))}
        </table>

        <Line
          data={state}
          options={{
            title: {
              display: true,
              text: "Plot of E_RAB_Setup_Success_Rate",
              fontSize: 20,
            },
            legend: {
              display: true,
              position: "right",
            },
          }}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SelectSingle;
`
Backend code 

    const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const mysql = require("mysql2");
const app = express();

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "a",
  password: "123",
  database: "aa",
});

connection.connect((err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected to MySQL Server!");
});

app.use(cors());
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  connection.query("SELECT * FROM africell_data LIMIT 10", (err, rows) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.json(rows);
  });
});

app.get("/sites", function (req, res) {
  connection.query(
    `SELECT eNodeB_Name,Cell_Name,Traffice_Date,E_RAB_Setup_Success_Rate,Data_Traffic_DL,Data_Traffic_UL,G_UL_Throughput_IK FROM africell_data`,
    (err, rows) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      res.json(rows);
    }`enter code here`
  );
});

app.listen(8080, (req, res) => {
  console.log(`The app is connected on port 8080`);
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIEFa.png)

Comment: Ok so if I am correct you have a bunch of fields and you wish to have a filter for those fields right and you are using react?

Comment: On another note, the work you're doing to create the state object is a bit out of place in a react component, it'd probably be better to wrap all that stuff in a function at least, then reference the function in your Line component.

Answer (score 0):

It appears in your handleDate and handleEndDate functions, you're filtering only for sites which have the specified date (`site.Traffice_Date === getDate(e)`), which would explain why you're only seeing one date. Try updating the code in your filter block to look for all sites with date above or below your start and end dates, as desired.